# Cohomology ring $H^*(BG,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ for $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes B^2\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, spectral-sequences, classifying-spaces

$$
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
$$

Consider the group $G=\Z_2\ltimes B^2\Z^2$ where $\Z_2$ acts on $\Z^2$ by interchanging the two factors of $\Z^2$, hence $\Z_2$ also acts on the Eilenberg-MacLane space $B^2\Z^2=K(\Z^2,2)$.

Question: what is the mod 2 cohomology ring $H^*(BG,\Z_2)$ and its module structure over the mod 2 Steenrod algebra?

Here is my attempt (xymatrix failed to compile):
There is a fibration sequence
$$B^3\Z^2\to BG\to B\Z_2.$$

So we have the Serre spectral sequence
$$H^p(B\Z_2,H^q(B^3\Z^2,\Z_2))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(BG,\Z_2).$$

Comment: This is standard.  As a matter of fact you can replace $B^3Z^2$ by $X^2$ (so $X$ will be $K(Z,3)$).  Just write $H^*(X^2)=F\oplus T$ where $F$ is free, $T$ is trivial $Z/2$-module, and $E^{\infty}$ looks like $H^0(Z/2,F)\oplus H^*(BZ/2)\otimes T$.  I guess normally you can deduce the Steenrod algebra's action just using the Steenrod diagonal, but at worst, the cohomology of the space you are after is detected by $X\times X$ and $X\times BZ/2$.  Another way of determining the A-module structure is to consider your space as a stable summand of $QK(Z,3)$ and use the Nishida relations.

Comment: (1) Thanks so much! I voted up. Could you provide a great ref on Nishida relations?

Comment: (2) What is your $Q$ in the $(,3)$?

Comment: $Q=\Omega ^{\infty }\Sigma ^{\infty}$

Comment: Anything that treats the homology of infinite loop spaces will do,  for example there is May's book, or this paper https://people.math.harvard.edu/~dwilson/research/classical-power.pdf by Dylan Wilson

Comment: @user43326 thanks! --- what does it mean: the free F and trivial T in your comment?

Comment: $F$ is  a free $Z/2[Z/2]$-module, $T$ is a module with trivial $Z/2$ action.  So, if $a_i$'s form a basis of $H^*(X)$, $a_i\otimes a_i$ form a basis of $T$ and $a_i \otimes a_j + a_j \otimes a_i$ form a basis of $F$.